# 'Object? Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Good morning guys getting an error when trying to "Document2.0 if getting data from someone ready" Contains all the data of this instant document.

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
                        snapshot.data!.docs.reversed.toList();
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: documents.length,
                        reverse: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ChatMessage(documents[index].data);
                        });
```

"The argument type 'Object? Function()' cannot be assigned parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'".[image]

Comment: Please put the code as text in the question body using the Code Sample option {}.

Comment: `data` is a method, so `data()`.